# Not Unlocking the record after final rejection of approval process

Tags: approval-process

When approver rejected the approval process, it should go to the final rejection and unlock the record but this is not happening. We have to do it by code ? or is there any other approach for this ?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to include more detail about what you built out. Without that, it will be difficult to assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply specify a Final Rejection Action of "Record Unlock". This should have been specified by default, but you can modify the behavior by clicking Edit under Final Rejection Actions for the Record Lock action.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but Record Unlock is already specified, still it is locking the record. Is it some settings or something which is locking the record ?